# How to create timestamps for raw H264 to make it VFR using audio as reference?

Tags: audio, video, sync, framerate

I had an MP4 screen recording which got corrupted (missing moov atom).

I tried `untrunc`, `recover_mp4_to_h264` and `MP4Fix`, and the latter gave me a complete result.

However, the result was pure h264 and pure aac files. The aac was playing in perfect timing, but the h264 seems to be without VFR timestamps, and hence playing it at any CFR framerate results in the audio being out of sync.

I think the only way to fix it is to manually divide video segments and combine them in such a way that the sound matches.

The problem is that the audio is 1 hour and 23 minutes long, so it's a lot of frames. Videos recorded similarly have an average framerate of 45 FPS (min ~5, max ~57).

Is there any easy way in which I can just pause at a frame and drag it to the right audio marker, by increasing or decreasing the speed and not disrupting other frames aligned in the same manner?